# Adding jQuery dependency prevents my script from enqueuing/loading

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

This works:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_script_enqueue');
function custom_script_enqueue() {
  wp_enqueue_style(
       'customstyle',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/theme.css',
        array(),
        '0.1',
        'all'
  );

  wp_enqueue_script(
     'customjs',
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/js.js',
      array(),
      '0.1',
      true
  );
}
```

But my custom JS is going to use a couple of jQuery calls. It's currently failing because jQuery is loaded after this custom script and so jQuery is coming back as being `undefined` on page load.

I read some answers here and tried this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_script_enqueue');
function custom_script_enqueue() {
  wp_enqueue_style(
      'customstyle',
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/theme.css',
       array(),
      '0.1',
      'all'
   );

   wp_enqueue_script(
      'customjs',
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/js.js',
      array('jQuery'),
      '0.1',
      true
   );
}
```

Now, my custom script doesn't load at all. It's nowhere to be found when I `view-source:` on the page.

I tried replacing `wp_enqueue_script` with `wp_register_script` and then calling `wp_enqueue_script('customjs');` below, but although it throws no errors, I get the same (lack of) result.

Comment: Note that these snippets were edited to remove the `get_template_directory_uri();` for readability.

Comment: I'd suggest leaving `get_template_directory_uri();` in the code. Use concatenation if it will help with readability. Not everyone reads the comments and there's a big difference between using `get_template_directory_uri()` and not, in this case.

Comment: The string for the jQuery dependency is actually, `jquery` (all lowercase).

Comment: @DaveRomsey That's it! Please add it as an answer and I'll mark as correct. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The handle for the jQuery dependency is actually, `jquery` (all lowercase and case sensitivity matters).

The complete list of JavaScript handles are documented [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) in the Theme Developer Handbook.

Comment: Awesome. Those little things that trip us up when we think everything "looks right". Thanks!